# Tampermonkey on Mozilla Firefox (Change redirect link to direct one)

Tags: redirect, tampermonkey

How can I make a tampermonkey scripts to remove some url header from website. When I click the download link, it goes to the another page and ask comfirmation to leave

The original link I got after clicking download
 -   http://website/go/?https://www31.zippyshare.com/v/123454232/file.html

Supposed that I want to go to direct download link instead
 -   https://www31.zippyshare.com/v/123454232/file.html

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the document.links-array with a forEach()-loop and replace all links:

```
[...document.links].forEach(i => i.href = i.href.replace('http://website/go/?',''));
```